# DuckDuckGo finds some answers that are not found by the search bar

Tags: bug, search

Today, I tried to use the TeX & LaTeX search bar to find examples of code that use the macro `text_expand` (a macro from the l3text module)

The following lists what I tried searching.

- `text_expand` [(link)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=text_expand)
- `"text_expand"` [(link)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22text_expand%22)
- `\text_expand` [(link)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Ctext_expand)
- `"\text_expand"` [(link)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22%5Ctext_expand%22)
- `code:\text_expand` [(link)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=code%3A%5Ctext_expand)
- `code:"\text_expand"` [(link)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=code%3A%22%5Ctext_expand%22)

In all those searches, I got the following message:

```
We couldn't find anything for <<my input>>
Search options: <<options for my input>>
Try different or less specific keywords.
```

However, when I tried searching `site:tex.stackexchange.com "text_expand"` in DuckDuckGo [(link)](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=h_&q=site%3Atex.stackexchange.com+%22text_expand%22&ia=web), I found three results (see screenshot below.)

[image]

Why doesn't the search bar list those answers that are found by DuckDuckGo?

Comment: Because the site search function has always been terrible, and continues to be so.

Comment: you can use duckduck or google or SEDE and only as a last resort use the built in site search